# LinearGradient displays wrong colors when using colors in P3 colorspace (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, colors, color-space

I am trying to copy colors from a design drawing in P3 colorspace on my Mac into a SwiftUI iPhone app design but the colors in the app don't match the colors I see on my Mac screen.

I drew the iPhone app design drawing on my Mac using P3 colorspace and then copied the RGB values of the colors into my app using commands like the ones shown below. Originally I used Affinity Designer to draw them but just to be sure that Affinity isn't giving me wrong numbers, I duplicated part of the design using Apple's Keynote. I got exactly the same RGB numbers from both apps.

Here's how I defined the colors:

```
// colors for home screen background gradient
static let Color_Home_BG_BottomLight = Color(.displayP3, red: 139.0/255.0, green: 197.0/255.0, blue: 226.0/255.0)
static let Color_Home_BG_TopLight = Color(.displayP3, red: 0.0/255.0, green: 123.0/255.0, blue: 184.0/255.0)
```

And this is how I used the colors to create a gradient background for the app:

```
VStack(spacing : 0){
   [...]
}
.background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Constants.Color_Home_BG_BottomLight, Constants.Color_Home_BG_TopLight]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)
```

When I take a screenshot of the iPhone app and airdrop it to my Mac, or when I take a screenshot of my design drawing and airdrop it to my iPhone, it shows that the colors I am getting from the iPhone are not the same as what I drew in the design software on my Mac. I'm looking at the images side-by-side on the same screen so I'm sure it's not just caused by differences between the two monitors. It looks like what I'm getting in the app UI is not really P3 color. All the colors are less saturated.

[Screenshot from Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEubY.jpg)
[Screenshot from iPhone app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKEsk.png)

To be sure that I'm not just getting wrong numbers from Affinity Designer AND Keynote, I also tried using the color eyedropper tool in the ColorSync Utility on Mac to get the RGB values, but that didn't work either.

EDIT:

I tried switching from `Color(.displayP3,...)` to `Color(.sRGB, ...)`. For the gradient, the change had no effect but for solid colors it does. So it seems possible that the `LinearGradient` command is not accepting P3 colors as input.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the LinearGradient function of SwiftUI. I created a new empty Xcode app project with SwiftUI and pasted the code snipped below into ContentView.swift. The code generates a full-screen background of solid color by creating a LinearGradient that starts and ends with the same displayP3 color. Then it draws a rectangle on top of that background and fills it with the same color. On my iPhone 11 running iOS 16.3 the rectangle displays with a different color from the background but on the iPhone simulator in Xcode the rectangle is the same color as the background.

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let color1 = Color(.displayP3, red: 0.0/255.0, green: 123.0/255.0, blue: 184.0/255.0)
    
    let color2 = Color(.displayP3, red: 139.0/255.0, green: 197.0/255.0, blue: 226.0/255.0)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // This rectangle shouldn't be visible because it's filled with the same color as the background. But it IS visible on my iPhone.
            RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity)
                .foregroundColor(color1)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity)
        .padding()
        .background(
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [color1, color1]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[Screenshot from iPhone showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgX1t.jpg)
[Screenshot from simulator working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxW7h.png)

I reported the bug to Apple.

Comment: That's the exact same screenshot from my device. so you may consider if your iPhone display is not functional.

Comment: @NeZha Your phone looks like the simulator screenshot? Which iOS version do you have?

Comment: I used my MacBook to check your screenshots, and I also copied the code and run by Xcode14 with simulator 16.2 and my iPhone 16.02.